# I want to set the values but getInt and getString is not working but it shows getAsInt and getAsString, and aslo not accepting the members names

Tags: java, android

JsonObject first_day_from_api = (JsonObject) consolodated_weather_list.get(0);
first_day.setWeather_state_name(first_day_from_api.getAsString("weather_state_name"));

////weather_state_name is not accepted by

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use **JSONObject** but you're using **JsonObject**

import **org.json.JSONObject**